Question about convergence of a sequence of functions from $\Gamma$
Let $\rho(z) = \big|\frac{z-i}{z+i}\big|$. If $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then we have that $\left(\rho\left(\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}\right)\right)^2 = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 -2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2}$. All is good until here.
I need to show that if $(\phi_n)$ is a sequence of distinct elements of $\Gamma$ (so, $\phi_n \ne \phi_m$ for $n \ne m$), then $\rho(\phi_n(i)) \to 1$. I observed that for a given $R < \infty$ we have that there are only finitely many $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 < R$. So, how can I continue?
Note: $\Gamma$ is the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ that correspond to the group $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Let $y_n = a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+c_{n}^{2}+d_{n}^{2}$, I will show that if $\phi_n(z) = \frac{a_nz+b_n}{c_nz+d_n} \in \Gamma$ then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} y_{n} = +\infty.
$$
Let $N>0$, as you have shown, there are finitely many $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 < N$, so, there is $n_{0}$ such that $y_n \geq N$ for all $n \geq n_0$, because, assuming by contradiction that there is not, then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find $n_1>n$ such that $y_{n_1} < N$, so we can construct an infinite sequence of vectors $(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$ satisfying
$$
a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+c_{n}^{2}+d_{n}^{2} < N
$$
which is a contradiction, hence such $n_0$ exists for every $N>0$ and therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_{n} = +\infty$. Back to your question we have
$$
\rho(\phi_n(i)) = \frac{y_n - 2}{y_n + 2}  \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1
$$

But how I know that if $\phi_n \ne \phi_m$, then $\phi_n(i) \ne \phi_m(i)$? because $y_n$ can have multiple terms that are repeated

If $\phi_n \neq \phi_m$ then $\phi_n(i)$ can be equal to $\phi_m(i)$, but the point is that the vectors $(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n)$ and $(a_m,b_m,c_m,d_m)$ are different, so this equality will happen at most a finite number of times (this is due to the fact you mentioned in the post), but the main point is looking at the norm of these vectors, due to the fact you proved, the norms can repeat at most a finite number of times and since it is a sequence of integers, they will go to infinity
